# Every two columns are merged into one column in

Tags: python, matlab

I have a text file that looks like this
[image: It's 432 rows and more than 1.2 million columns]
I want to join each ATGC pairwise, starting with the seventh column, to achieve this effect:
[image: The two base pairs after splicing are still separated by a space]
I tried to do this on linux using the awk command, but it was too slow：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJPu2.png)
thank you very much!

Use code in any language, hopefully python

Comment: We want to see you try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**awk solution**

I have an alternative `awk` solution that uses global substitutions rather than loops to format the data. I suspect this will be faster than what you tried but do not have your file to try it on.

This is the solution, (replace `data.txt` with the path to your data file):

```
awk '{$1 =$1"*"$2"*"$3"*"$4"*"$5"*"$6"*"; $2=$3=$4=$5=$6=""; print $0}' data.txt | awk 'BEGIN{FS="*"} {gsub(/ /,"",$0);gsub(/.{2}/,"& ",$7); print $0}'
```

**Explanation**

The first part of this procedure rewrites the first field `$1` to a string containing the first 6 fields concatenated, and ending, with intervening asterisks (*) - chosen as a unique character, choose a character that is not elsewhere in your file. fields `$2` to `$6` inclusive are set to empty strings before the new version of the line `$0` is printed to `stdout`.

At this stage the output has many unwanted spaces because the empty fields `$2` to `$6` still have their output-field-separators (spaces).

The output is piped into a second awk procedure that delimits the fields by asterisk `BEGIN{FS="*"}`, giving a total of 7 fields with many unwanted spaces.

Global substitution is used to replace all spaces in the record (`$0`) with empty strings using `gsub(/ /,"",$0)`.

Because the fields are defined by asterisk, the entire sequence (GATC) data, now devoid of any spaces, is held in a single field, the last field `$7`.

A second global substitution is used to insert a space after every second character in this sequence: `gsub(/.{2}/,"& ",$7)`.

Finally, printing the entire record (`print $0`) outputs the data with the unaltered output-field-separator (a space) effectively replacing the asterisks.

**example**

I tested the procedure with a file structured as follows:

```
(data.txt file)
one two three four five six A A C C G G C C G G
```

output:

```
one two three four five six AA CC GG CC GG
```

**edit - dealing with excessive field numbers**

The OP reported the above solution failed in their case with the message that the maximum number of fields (~32k) had been exceeded.

One work-around is to use `gawk`, the GNU implementation of `awk` (inbuilt in many linux distributions or available at: https://www.gnu.org/software/software.html), which can handle more fields than awk.

**Alternative Solution using `sed` and `awk`**

Alternatively, the data could be pre-processed to create a smaller number of fields by inserting a unique character with the stream editor `sed`. The data in the OP's data that needs reformatting is present in fields 7..n where n is large, and can exceed 32k. By placing a unique character immediately before the start of these fields, `awk` can split each line (record) at the unique character resulting in only 2 fields to process. In the same way suggested for the earlier solution, the required changes can be made by applying global substitutions to field 2.

The solution becomes simpler than the original as the spaces between the first six fields are untouched:

```
sed 's/ /*/6' data.txt | awk 'BEGIN{FS="*"} {gsub(/ /,"",$2); gsub(/.{2}/,"& ",$2); print $0}
```

(change data.txt to the path to your data file)

**explanation**

`sed` substitutes the sixth space in each original line (record) with an asterisk (must be unique): `sed 's/ /*/6'`

The `stdout` is pipped into `awk` where a `BEGIN` block sets the field-separator to an asterisk. Awk now sees two fields for each line, one containing (space-separated) columns 1-6, the other containing the ATCG sequence stream separated by spaces.

Awk can now replace the spaces from the sequence data with empty string by targetting a global substitution to field 2: `gsub(/ /,"",$2)`

Lastly, field 2 is again processed to insert a space every second character using `gsub(/.{2}/,"& ",$2)`, before the output is printed.

**caveat**
Whether this alternative solution will overcome the field-limit problem depends on how `awk` interprets `$0` (the whole line) internally. My hunch is that it does not view it as a collection of fields but rather views it as a single string. If so, and if strings of that length can be handled, it should work. (An informative experiment). If there is a limit to string length, the procedure could be modified to insert several asterisks across the sequence data, say in 1000 blocks, with each record processed as before.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your proposed solution, but when I try the command you give, the system prompts:
awk: program limit exceeded: maximum number of fields size=32767

Comment: @shanwa the simplest workaround if the field limit is reached is to try `gawk` (the gnu implementation of `awk`) which  has much higher field limits. It may already be on your machine or is easily downloaded from gnu.org. The command would be the same except for replacing 'awk' with 'gawk' at the start. Meantime I will think of other approaches but might need to "know your data", e.g. col 6  - is it always a number of known range? always negative? etc. We need to define features of the data that allow us to separate cols 1-6 from rest (without relying on spaces)

Comment: @shanwa I've edited my answer to include a possible work-around. See **Alternative Solution** in edit.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your help. After I changed awk to gawk, the program quickly gave me the result I wanted, which only took about one minute. Secondly, I also tried the solution you provided by using sed and awk. By comparison, this solution is very slow. I have tried it for 12 hours without any results. Finally, thank you again for your help.

Comment: @shanwa Thanks for the feedback, very interesting. I don't know why the sed and awk procedure would be so slow but it's really useful to know for future problems. In case I get time to investigate, it would be useful to now roughly how big your files are, and how many bases are in a typical line. I'd really appreciate it if you could let me know. Thanks for accepting the answer.

Comment: Hello, my file size is close to 1G, the number of bases in each line is about 1.2 million, there are 432 lines in total. If you need my files for testing, you can download them here:https://pan.quark.cn/s/d8f198a0ee46     If this link does not allow you to access the file, please let me know and I will try another way to provide you with the file.